# Assigning Datatable as datasource to RADGrid with different data types

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid, telerik-grid

I need to assign a datatable as the datasource for the telerik RADGrid. the datatable has datatypes like string, int, bool etc whereas the radgrid columns are of different types (Hyperlink,image etc)

i just need to use the string values in the datatable to build the hyperlink column. can you suggest which event I can use to do this? When i assign a datatable as a datasource to a grid, it assumes the grid column datatypes to be same as the source data types...Am I right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `DataNavigateUrlFields`, `DataNavigateUrlFormatString`, `DataTextField`, and `DataTextFormatString` properties of `<telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn />`.  You should be able to do something like:

```
<telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn
    DataNavigateUrlFields="categoryId,productId"
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="productDetail.aspx?category={0}&product={1}"
    DataTextField="productName"
    DataTextFormatString="View {0} details" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `GridBoundColumn` or `GridTemplateColumn`. There is a `DataType` property, but you shouldn't need it.

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Foo" DataField="Foo" DataType="System.String" ...>
```